# How to add popup image in to dropzone thumbnail?

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

Here, I wanted to add popup light-box library to my dropzone js thumbnail that will show up image dialog when user click on each thumbnail. Here, I use this image popup library:
[magnific-popup](https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html). So I come up with my dropzone js script as below:

```js
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
  var myDropzone = new Dropzone('#myDropzone', {
    url: 'http://localhost/Upload/',
    init: function() {
      this.on('thumbnail', function(file) {
        $('.dz-image').append('<div class="dz-image-overlay"></div>')

        /* show preview icon under image thumbnail */
        var image_name = file.name
        var dataURL = file.dataURL
        var preview_element = file.previewElement;

        /* initialize image popup */
        $('.dz-image-overlay').magnificPopup({
          // delegate: 'a',
          items: {
            src: file.dataURL
          },
          type: 'image'
        });
      })
    }


  })
});
```

```css
form.dropzone {
  padding: 0;
}

div.dropzone {
  width: 330px;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.dragover {
  border: 0.5px solid blue !important;
}

.dz-error-mark {
  display: none !important;
}

.dz-details,
.dz-progress {
  display: none !important;
}

.dz-image img {
  position: relative !important;
}

.dropzone .dz-preview:hover .dz-image img {
  /* disable default blur in drop zone */
  -webkit-transform: none !important;
  -moz-transform: none !important;
  -ms-transform: none !important;
  -o-transform: none !important;
  transform: none !important;
  -webkit-filter: none !important;
  filter: none !important;
}

.dz-image-overlay {
  /* center items inside it */
  /*display: flex;*/
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /* scratch it width, and height to match parent div */
  position: absolute;
  background: #00000014;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

.dropzone .dz-preview:hover .dz-image-overlay {
  display: flex !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- dropzone cdn -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.7.6/min/dropzone.min.js" integrity="sha512-KgeSi6qqjyihUcmxFn9Cwf8dehAB8FFZyl+2ijFEPyWu4ZM8ZOQ80c2so59rIdkkgsVsuTnlffjfgkiwDThewQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.7.6/dropzone.min.css" integrity="sha512-jU/7UFiaW5UBGODEopEqnbIAHOI8fO6T99m7Tsmqs2gkdujByJfkCbbfPSN4Wlqlb9TGnsuC0YgUgWkRBK7B9A==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<!-- manific popup cdn -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.0.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js" integrity="sha512-+m6t3R87+6LdtYiCzRhC5+E0l4VQ9qIT1H9+t1wmHkMJvvUQNI5MKKb7b08WL4Kgp9K0IBgHDSLCRJk05cFUYg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.0.0/magnific-popup.min.css" integrity="sha512-nIm/JGUwrzblLex/meoxJSPdAKQOe2bLhnrZ81g5Jbh519z8GFJIWu87WAhBH+RAyGbM4+U3S2h+kL5JoV6/wA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="dropzone" id="myDropzone"></div>
```

My dropzone area, thumbnail, and image popup dialog work fine, but the problem is the popup image shows only the last image when I drop into multiple images.

However, I want the image popup show image correctly according to which thumbnail user click on!

Please kindly help me with that. Thanks.

Comment: It is because they have the same class and you are appending it to .dz-image. try to append it using their id

Comment: how can I differentiate them if dropzone use the same classes and id? thanks

Comment: have you found answers for this?

Comment: @RobertAnthonyS.Tribiana sure I have an answer yesterday, I use file.name, the image name as an ID of class dz-image-overlay, and initialized image popup via that ID :)

Comment: Thanks very much @RobertAnthonyS.Tribiana

Comment: Great. sorry I don't have much time to create a jsbin/codepen for that but I am thinking the same way