# How to preview the user uploaded image with lightbox?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using [touchTouch](https://www.cssscript.com/mobile-lightbox-gallery-touch/) lightbox library in order to preview the images in a lightbox for a post that user wants to send.

This library is used on my back-end and works flawlessly (since the images are in a folder already), but in the front-end there is a form where the user may upload up to 20 images. The images will show their preview after the user has uploaded them (but before they have sent the form) and I want them to be clickable which would open a lightbox library.

The problem is that the library can't find the images location because they are not uploaded just yet.

I thought about using ajax to upload the images into a temporary folder and then remove the folder and its content once the form is submitted. Could this work (without refreshing the page or submitting the form), or are there any better alternative solutions for this?

JavaScript code to upload the files and show their preview + initialize lightbox library upon loading:

```
function ImgUpload() {
    var imgWrap = "";
    var imgArray = [];

    $('.upload__inputfile').each(function () {
        $(this).on('change', function (e) {
        imgWrap = $(this).closest('.upload__box').find('.upload__img-wrap');
        var maxLength = $(this).attr('data-max_length');

        var files = e.target.files;
        var filesArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(files);
        var iterator = 0;
        filesArr.forEach(function (f, index) {

            if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
                return;
            }

            if (imgArray.length > maxLength) {
                return false
            } else {
                var len = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
                    if (imgArray[i] !== undefined) {
                        len++;
                    }
                }

                if (len > maxLength) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    imgArray.push(f);

                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        var html = "<div class='upload__img-box'><a href='" + f.name + "' class='light-box' data-group='gallery'><div style='background-image: url(" + e.target.result + ")' data-number='" + $(".upload__img-close").length + "' data-file='" + f.name + "' class='img-bg'><div class='upload__img-close'></div></div></a></div>";
                        
                        imgWrap.append(html);
                        iterator++;
                        touchTouch(document.body.querySelectorAll('.light-box')); // Initialize the lightbox library

                        // Ajax script here to upload the images to a temporary folder?
                    }
                    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you could create a data-url from an uploaded image (before uploaded) which will allow you to access it locally and treat it like it was a regular image.

```js
imgInp.onchange = evt => {
  const [...files] = imgInp.files
  if (files) {
    files.forEach(function(file) {
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file)
      img.style.width = "200px"
      container.appendChild(img)

      // do your touchTouch initialization on the new elements
      // touchTouch(img);      

      img.onclick = function() {
        alert('lightbox');
      }
    })

  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>Choose Images, then click for lightbox.</p>
  <input accept="image/*" type='file' id="imgInp" multiple />
</form>

<div id="container">
</div>
```

Let's try with given code (not tested):

```js
ImgUpload();

function ImgUpload() {
  var imgWrap = "";
  var imgArray = [];

  $('.upload__inputfile').each(function() {
    $(this).on('change', function(e) {
      imgWrap = $(this).closest('.upload__box').find('.upload__img-wrap');
      var maxLength = $(this).attr('data-max_length');

      var files = e.target.files;
      var filesArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(files);
      var iterator = 0;
      filesArr.forEach(function(f, index) {

        if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
          return;
        }

        if (imgArray.length > maxLength) {
          return false
        } else {
          var len = 0;
          for (var i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
            if (imgArray[i] !== undefined) {
              len++;
            }
          }

          if (len > maxLength) {
            return false;
          } else {
            imgArray.push(f);

            var object_url = URL.createObjectURL(f)
            var html = "<div class='upload__img-box'><a href='" + f.name + "' class='light-box' data-group='gallery'><div style='background-image: url(" + object_url + ")' data-number='" + $(".upload__img-close").length + "' data-file='" + f.name + "' class='img-bg'><div class='upload__img-close'></div></div></a></div>";
            imgWrap.append(html);
            iterator++;
            setTimeout(function() {
              touchTouch(document.body.querySelectorAll('.light-box')); // Initialize the lightbox library

            });
            // Ajax script here to upload the images to a temporary folder?

          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>Choose Images, then click for lightbox.</p>
  <input accept="image/*" type='file' id="imgInp" class="upload__inputfile" multiple />
</form>

<div id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: Could this applied to the script that I have already? Because for styling purposes and for the lightbox purposes I need a div wrapping an **a** element, **img** element and another **div** element for the x button in case the user wants to remove a specific image. Have been trying to adapt your approach with this for a while now.

Comment: This works now but as long as I open the image, it seems to be stuck in an infinite loop (loading mouse icon) and I cannot change an image. The image is shown with a little opacity with it, but it shouldn't have that. Tried to remove setTimeout, iterator++ and different approaches, but it still hangs in a loop I guess. Will still try out something with this but other than that it kinda works.

Comment: obviously it would be wrong to initialize the touchTouch multiple times so it is best to initialize it for the same image that was appended , and not querySelectorAll()

Comment: I'm not sure if it's because of it. I made a new function called initLightbox and then there is the initialization and after that the **return** keyword (if it's really even needed). If I replace the **querySelectorAll** with **querySelector**, it just opens the image in the new window.

Comment: However I will accept this answer since it works this way. I just need to find the problem causing this. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you. I did try to find this touchTouch library but couldn't find CDN for a demonstration (that I would made here as snippet)

Comment: https://www.cssscript.com/mobile-lightbox-gallery-touch/ it was demonstrated in here. I realized the CSS file of touchTouch added .5 opacity and cursor: wait so there never were any issues with the script. Will override these styles or either use a different lightbox if the issues continue.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to convert the data obtained from the File interface to Base64 or DataURL.then set img src='data:image/png;base64str'

Comment: Have tried that before and it threw the same error. At least with Base64

Answer (score 0):

> are there any better alternative solutions for this?

Yes! I would recommend these js libraries

[Filepond by PQINA](https://pqina.nl/filepond/) and [Dropzone.js](https://www.dropzone.dev/js/)

Be advised that they both have image preview but not lightbox feature. But with Dropzone.js, this Stack Overflow thread might help [How to add popup image in to dropzone thumbnail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66420376/how-to-add-popup-image-in-to-dropzone-thumbnail)

Comment: This could be back-up plan if the custom function doesn't work as planned, but rather use own code than a library and then modify it for the lightbox.